# number of function calls growing

Tags: jquery-mobile

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/proud-picture

I stuck with strange behaviour of jQuery Mobile.
Think there is a problem with `$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function(event, ui) { ... }`

Assume we have multi-html single page jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 app (two pages `index.html` and `rollo.html`), ajaxEnabled = true.

Via links we can navigate from one page to another. On `index.html` we have a list of links, each one leads to `rollo.html` page. On `rollo.html` page we have button in top right corner with home icon - it will lead us back to `index.html`

I put `console.log("drawRollo")` in `$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function(event, ui) { ... }` event which is calling each time on `rollo.html` page so we can see in console that it was called.

I intentionally put different transition effects so we know from which page we have initial load.

Now, if first page will be `index.html` and then we go to `rollo.html` via link, then go back to `index.html` and so on - each time `rollo.html` is opened number of calls of `drawRollo` is growing - at first it is one, then two, then it's being called three times and so on. **Why this happens???**

On the other hand, if we start from `rollo.html` and then navigate via link to `index.html`, then go back to `rollo.html` and so on - each time `drawRollo` method is being called only once.

Comment: here is the JQM documentation about [Navigation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/). Maybe you will find something useful.

Comment: @deblocker it was first thing I did, thanks. I didn’t see what I did wrong according to it - so I created this question